# vision_ssd_detect cannot be launched (fine compilation of ssdcaffe and CUDA enabled device)

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

It's not possible to launch vision_ssd_detect because it is not possible to find the "libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3". Compilation with ssdcaffe went well (followed http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html) and then make & make distribute.
I am not able to track where this issue is coming from. I attach the terminal output for ./colcon_release with CUDA flag 1 for debugging purposes.

System Specs:

Ubuntu 16.04
ROS Kinetic
Autoware git commit: 42aba146
CUDA 8.0

Autoware build result - SSDCAFFE build result and .launch log file:
1- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Epki9X411EMziRscY2ppo62G-HkDo8sl/view?usp=sharing
2- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UPDzZxQe3Y4PDWQkRQZ2FVPCXJ5LCdZE/view?usp=sharing
3- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ltTWGH-J2CPP9PMI2a5xXwcI1g2oAg42/view?usp=sharing

/home/ocp/Autoware/ros/install/runtime_manager/lib/runtime_manager/runtime_manager_dialog.py:2865: wxPyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated item.
wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
Unable to register with master node [http://localhost:11311]: master may not be running yet. Will keep trying.
loading qs.yaml
Subscribe[localization] topic=/ndt_stat, key=/ndt_stat.NDTStat.exe_time
Subscribe[detection] topic=/topic2, key=/topic2
Subscribe[detection] topic=/topic1, key=/topic1
loading setup.yaml
['rosparam', 'set', 'tf_x', '1.2']
['rosparam', 'set', 'tf_y', '0.0']
['rosparam', 'set', 'tf_z', '2.0']
['rosparam', 'set', 'tf_yaw', '0.0']
['rosparam', 'set', 'tf_pitch', '0.0']
['rosparam', 'set', 'tf_roll', '0.0']
['rosparam', 'set', 'localizer', 'velodyne']
loading map.yaml
loading sensing.yaml
loading computing.yaml
loading interface.yaml
loading data.yaml
loading simulation.yaml
['rosparam', 'set', '/use_sim_time', 'false']
loading status.yaml
loading state.yaml
loading topics.yaml
['roslaunch', 'vision_ssd_detect', 'vision_ssd_detect.launch', 'score_threshold:=0.6', 'image_src:=/image_raw', 'network_definition_file:=/home/ocp/ssdcaffe/models/VGGNet/VOC0712Plus/SSD_300x300/deploy.prototxt', 'pretrained_model_file:=/home/ocp/ssdcaffe/models/VGGNet/VOC0712Plus/SSD_300x300/VGG_VOC0712Plus_SSD_300x300_iter_240000.caffemodel', 'use_gpu:=True', 'gpu_device_id:=0']
pid=2337
sched policy=OTHER prio=0
/home/ocp/Autoware/ros/install/vision_ssd_detect/lib/vision_ssd_detect/vision_ssd_detect: error while loading shared libraries: libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vision_ssd_detect-1] process has died [pid 2356, exit code 127, cmd /home/ocp/Autoware/ros/install/vision_ssd_detect/lib/vision_ssd_detect/vision_ssd_detect __name:=vision_ssd_detect __log:=/home/ocp/.ros/log/d9212ea6-9a00-11e9-8b7c-a4fc771a0d0d/vision_ssd_detect-1.log].
log file: /home/ocp/.ros/log/d9212ea6-9a00-11e9-8b7c-a4fc771a0d0d/vision_ssd_detect-1*.log
/image_raw

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327331/vision_ssd_detect-cannot-be-launched-(fine-compilation-of-ssdcaffe-and-cuda-enabled-device)/) by [cassini.huygens](https://answers.ros.org/users/42910/cassini.huygens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2019-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error itself is telling you that the linux linker cannot found `libcaffe.so`.

`/lib/vision_ssd_detect/vision_ssd_detect: error while loading shared libraries: libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3`

You'll need to either

1. add the path where that `.so` file is located to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or
2. "install" or move caffe headers/libraries to the system path, and update the libraries cache.

Supponsing you cloned Caffe to `/home/YOUR_USER/caffe/`

If you go for 1.
`$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/YOUR_USER/caffe/distribute/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

If you prefer 2.
`$ cd /home/YOUR_USER/caffe && sudo make install && sudo ldconfig`

Then you should be able to run the node.

---

Originally posted by [amc-nu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41091/amc-nu/) with karma: 136 on 2019-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [msw](https://answers.ros.org/users/49221/msw/) on 2019-11-11**:
I have same problem like above,

```
/lib/vision_ssd_detect/vision_ssd_detect: error while loading shared libraries: libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3
```

but your solution doesnt work for me, either option 1 or option 2. and couldnt do `sudo make install`, just `sudo make` or `sudo make all`. Do you have any other suggestion?

Thanks in advance.